# Order by in a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my query :

```
select count(1) into isMyCarExists 
    from CAR
    where ID_MODEL = (select ID 
                        from MODEL
                        where TYPE = 'SUV'
                        and rownum <= 1
                        order by DATE_UPDATE desc);
```

I want to `count` how many rows in `CAR` have the latest version (`DATE_UPDATE desc`) of the `MODEL` `'SUV'`.

With this query, I got `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`...

I'm using Oracle Database 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about that error first. Your query is wrong functionally. Order by and rownum don't go together.

Since you are not on 12c, you need to have the `order by` first and then use `where rownum = 1` in the outer query. Else, in 12c, it is quite easy using TOP-N query as `fetch first 1 rows only`

Answer (score 3):

Even if you fixed the query, it wouldn't do what you want.  The `where` is executed before the `order by`.

If the `id`s are assigned in increasing order, then this should work:

```
select count(*) as isMyCarExists
from car c
where id_model = (select max(id)
                  from model
                  where type = 'SUV'
                 );
```

Alternatively, use analytic functions:

```
select count(*) as isMyCarExists
from car c
where id_model = (select m.id
                  from (select m.*, row_number() over (order by date_update desc) as seqnum
                        from model m
                        where m.type = 'SUV'
                       ) m
                  where seqnum = 1
                 );
```